# How to store/print multiple callback values on python telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to build a simple telegram bot running python-telegram-bot.

By doing the below, when i do "/start", I'm able to see the inlineKeyboard but I'm only able to print the "last" function's user input, which is the letter.

How can I print both inputs in the same "combine" function?

```
def start(update: Update, _: CallbackContext) -> None:
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('1', callback_data='1'),
                InlineKeyboardButton('2', callback_data='2'),
                InlineKeyboardButton('3', callback_data='3'),
                InlineKeyboardButton('4', callback_data='4')]]
    update.message.reply_text('Number?', reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard))

def letter(update: Update, _: CallbackContext) -> None:
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('A', callback_data='A'),
                InlineKeyboardButton('B', callback_data='B'),
                InlineKeyboardButton('C', callback_data='C'),
                InlineKeyboardButton('D', callback_data='D')]]
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    query.edit_message_text('First letter?', reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard))

def combine(update: Update, _: CallbackContext) -> None:
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    query.edit_message_text(text=f"You selected {query.data}")
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean both inputs?

Comment: @BeppeC, means i want both the number and letter that the user selected using the InlineKeyboardButton, but when i print "You selected" im only getting the letter (last user input)

Answer (score 1):

> means i want both the number and letter that the user selected using the InlineKeyboardButton, but when i print "You selected" im only getting the letter (last user input)

The update can not contain information about the first button click. You'll have to keep track of what the user selects. Note that PTB comes with a built-in mechanism for storing user/chat related data. See this [wiki page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Storing-bot,-user-and-chat-related-data) for more details.